# Xamarin/Android write of camrea

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using Android;
using AndroidX.Core.Content;
using Java.Util.Concurrent;
using AndroidX.Camera.Lifecycle;
using AndroidX.Camera.Core;
namespace BadClaims
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        private string[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera, Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage };
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) return;
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera, Manifest.Permission.RecordAudio, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 10);
        }
        private IExecutorService cameraExecutor { get; set; } = null!;
        private bool allPermissionsGranted() => REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.Select(x => ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(BaseContext, x)).ToList().All(x => x == Permission.Granted);
        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            cameraExecutor?.Shutdown();
        }
        private async void startCam() {
          var cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.GetInstance(BaseContext);
           // var x= cameraProviderFuture.Get();
     
         //   var preview = new Preview.Builder().Build().;
         
           // cameraProviderFuture.AddListener( ,ContextCompat.GetMainExecutor(BaseContext));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can se i try to understand xamarin  what i like to focus on is  "var cameraProviderFuture"
What i like to is that i like to stream to MP4 file.. and i can choice between any camrea in a android.
Basic
1.) get all camrea devices in android.
2.) Start and stop..
3.) Make it to a format maybe MP4 easy format to understand to a stream..
4.) whit out any surix or layout

I try to convert from a java..
Im pretty lost..
i cant finde any infomation about how to finde how many camera..
I like to use. Camerax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries using Camera2 needs have been integrated into the xamarin, so you can use it according to the native android official document.

Official binding library document for Camera2:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/tree/main/source/androidx.camera

Binding library doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/

Comment: but i thing to rewrite it to c#... more easy but i thing you can help me if you like can you